# Can you prove this identity involving the divisor sum function?

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions

Let $$\sigma(n)=\sum_{d\mid n}d$$ the sum of divisor function. I've deduced, but I don't know how prove directly

$$\sigma(n)=\sum_{m=1}^{n}\sum_{k=1}^{m}(-1)^{nk}\cos\left(\frac{\pi n(2-m)k}{m}\right).$$

> **Question.** Can you prove it? **Thanks in advance.**

Comment: Other example $$\sigma(6)=\sum_{i=1}^6\sum_{j=1}^i\cos\left(6\frac{2\pi(1-i)j}{i}\right)=13+(-1-\sqrt{5})/2+(\sqrt{5}-1)/2=12.$$

In **Wolfram Language**:

 Sum[cos(2*(pi)*6(1-i)j/i), {i, 1, 6}, {j, 1, i}]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose we have the usual $\sigma(n)  = \sum_{d|n} d$ and wish to show
that

$$\sigma(n) = \sum_{m=1}^n
\sum_{k=1}^m (-1)^{nk} 
\cos\left(\frac{\pi n(2-m)k}{m}\right).$$

This is

$$\sum_{m=1}^n
\sum_{k=1}^m (-1)^{nk}  (-1)^{nk}
\cos\left(\frac{2\pi nk}{m}\right)
= \Re
\left(\sum_{m=1}^n
\sum_{k=1}^m
e^{2\pi i nk /m}\right).$$

which is
$$\Re
\left(\sum_{m=1}^n e^{2\pi i n/m}
\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}
e^{2\pi i nk /m}\right)
= \Re
\left(\sum_{m=1}^n e^{2\pi i n/m}
\times m \times [[m|n]]\right)
\\ = \Re\left(\sum_{m|n} m\right) = \sigma(n)$$

as claimed.

Here we have used the fact that

$$\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}
e^{2\pi i nk /m}
= \frac{e^{2\pi i n}-1}{e^{2\pi i n/m}-1}
= 0$$

when $e^{2\pi i n/m} \ne 1$ and $m$ otherwise which yields
$$m\times[[m|n]].$$

Comment: Very thanks much, incredible. I take notes to study your proof.